# Materializecss autocomplete overlapped by Firefox autcomplete

Tags: html, firefox, materialize

I don't understand why firefox autocomplete is overlapping my materializecss autocomplete field.

[image: by]

Hello, I don't understand why firefox autocomplete is overlapping my materializecss autocomplete field.

```
            <form action="{{ path('search_result') }}" method="get" class="searchForm">
                <div class="col s11 m6 offset-m3 input-field">
                    <label for="search_bar" class="active">Où boirons nous ?</label>
                    <input type="text" class="autocomplete white-text" id="search_bar" placeholder="" name="bar_name"
                       autofocus/>
                </div>
                <div class="col s1">
                    <input type="image" src="{{ asset('build/images/Loupe.svg') }}" class="searchBtn" border="0"
                       alt="Rechercher"/>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `autocomplete="off"` tag in your input definition. So your code would look like

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="autocomplete white-text"
  id="search_bar" placeholder="" name="bar_name" autofocus/>
```